Mostrar y Ocultar elementos al hacer scroll (librería perfect scrollbar)
tengo el siguiente código que quiero que por default se oculte y que al hacer scroll 200 se muestre


                    <div class="card bg-gradient-light" id="mi-elemento" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="card-body p-2">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="m-0">
                                    <a href="mis-bims.html" class="d-flex">
                                        <div class="align-self-center">
                                            <dotlottie-player
                                                src="https://lottie.host/7d5e390f-a0e9-4503-b199-ebd0732dc5c1/cx1fp1OuuM.json"
                                                background="transparent" speed="1"
                                                style="width: 35px; height: 35px;" loop autoplay></dotlottie-player>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="align-self-center">
                                            <p class="text-xxs text-dark mb-0 lh-1"> <span
                                                    class="font-weight-bold">Miguel Angel</span> tienes:</p>
                                            <h5 class="d-flex font-weight-bolder m-0 text-primary lh-1">
                                                410 <span
                                                    class="text-xxs text-end font-weight-normal text-dark align-self-end ms-1 me-2">BIMS.</span>
                                            </h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

Antes he hecho esto con JS y funciona muy bien pero ahora creo que no sirve porque estoy utilizando la librería perfect scrollbar, alguién sabe como solucionarlo?

Podrias poner una imagen del resultado (lo he probado como snippet y no funciona, me parece que stackoverflow no tiene instalado perfectscrollbar)?
En cuanto a la libreria, yo te recomendaria usar JS, si como has dicho te ha funcionado, por que complicarse la vida con librerías? Usa JS y ya está
